# Finding value on a column based on another column and a parameter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns like this:

```
+-----+----+-------+
| 50  | 10 |   20  |
| 175 | 30 | 17.14 |
| 150 | 25 | 16.66 |
| 250 | 40 | 16    |
| 100 | 15 | 15    |
+-----+----+-------+
```

What I want to achieve is when I type a value in a completely other box, I want to find the highest value in C column with the value closest (or equal to) among the ones lower than the value I entered.

For example if I write 56 I want 20 to come as a result or 16.66 for 160.

I don't know if I can parametrize the input (56 and 160 in the example above) in Excel. Would be visually better if I could light up the line for the correct value.

I'm sure this is doable in Excel to some extent but I don't know how.

Comment: It's very doable. What have you tried? Please include that too =). Also what do you want to do with B column

Comment: I can get the max value in a range with MAX functions but parameterizing part and finding the value in C based on A part escapes me.

Comment: What do you want to return if the completed order is `75`? Value based on `50` or `100`?

Comment: Oh sorry, there is some misinformation on my part and I'll edit. It's a <= operation there.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained the purpose of column B but based on your question the following would work:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=INDEX(C1:C5,MATCH(MIN(ABS(A1:A5-E2)),ABS(A1:A5-E2),0))
```

> ***Note*** It's an array formula which need to be confirmed through <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Without pressing CSE, you could use the following formula:

```
=INDEX(C1:C5,MATCH(MIN(INDEX(ABS(A1:A5-E2),)),INDEX(ABS(A1:A5-E2),),0))
```